# Dice-rolling Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, dice

I completed writing a dice roll script in Python but I thought it looked too messy. Is there anything I should change here?

```
import random, os

class Dice:
    result = []
    total = 0

    def __roll_(sides=1):
        return random.randint(1, sides)

    def roll(sides=1, times=1):
        for time in range(0, times):
            Dice.result.append(Dice.__roll_(sides))
            Dice.result = Dice.result[len(Dice.result) - times:len(Dice.result)]
        Dice.sumResult()
        return Dice.result

    def sumResult():
        Dice.total = 0
        for num in range(0, len(Dice.result)):
            Dice.total += Dice.result[num]
        return Dice.total

    def saveResult(directory=''):
        if directory == '':
            savetxt = open('savedResult.txt', 'a+')
        else:
            savetxt = open(os.path.join(directory, 'savedResult.txt'), 'a+')
        savetxt.write(str(Dice.result) + '\n')
        savetxt.close()

    def saveTotal(directory=''):
        if directory == '':
            savetxt = open('savedTotal.txt', 'a+')
        else:
            savetxt = open(os.path.join(directory, 'savedTotal.txt'), 'a+')
        savetxt.write(str(Dice.total) + '\n')
        savetxt.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class is not a class, `self` is totally missing. You have to rewrite the whole thing.
Internal methods start with one single underscore `_roll`.
You can access lists from the end with negative indices, len in unnesseccary.
Never change the internal state of a instance and return a value. Do the one or the other.
You can join with empty strings, if is unneccessary.
Open files with the with-statement. Never use the string representation of python objects like lists or dicts for other purposes than debugging.
Remember the naming conventions in PEP-8.

```
import random
import os

class Dice:
    def __init__(self, sides=1):
        self.sides = sides
        self.result = []
        self.total = 0

    def _roll(self):
        return random.randint(1, self.sides)

    def roll(self, times=1):
        self.result[:] = [self._roll() for time in range(times)]
        self.sum_result()

    def sum_result(self):
        self.total = sum(self.result)

    def save_result(self, directory=''):
        with open(os.path.join(directory, 'savedResult.txt'), 'a') as txt:
            txt.write('%s\n' % ', '.join(map(str, self.result)))

    def save_total(directory=''):
        with open(os.path.join(directory, 'savedTotal.txt'), 'a') as txt:
            txt.write('%d\n' % self.total)
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, that's why it looked so bad! I knew I was missing something. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

@Daniel rightfully noted:

> Your class is not a class, `self` is totally missing

I am going to question the basis of your design, does a class represent the best way to program a Dice rolling script?

Even if you like the idea of a class, think about about the separation of concerns, why should a Dice know how to save its result to a file?

My implementation of the script just uses some functions, and i feel like this is a big simplification, remember OOP, as any programming paradigm, is not the final perfect solution to all design problems:

```
import random
import os

def roll(sides):
    return random.randint(1, sides)

def roll_many(sides, times):
    return (roll(sides) for time in range(times))

def save_list_to_file(list_, directory=''):
    with open(os.path.join(directory, 'savedResult.txt'), 'a') as txt:
        txt.write('%s\n' % ', '.join(map(str, list_)))

def save_number_to_file(n, directory=''):
    with open(os.path.join(directory, 'savedTotal.txt'), 'a') as txt:
        txt.write('%d\n' % n)
```

Comment: Thanks for the non-OOP answer; I find it great, but I'm planning on sticking with a class.